# What counts as a critical on defense?

Tags: combat, gurps, critical-hit

In GURPS Campaigns p381, it states that a critical success on defense causes the attacker to suffer a "critical miss."

Does a critical hit on defense count as a roll of 3 or 4?  If my parry is 15, does a roll of 5 count as a critical (a la attack rolls)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes.** Critical successes are a general mechanic in GURPS and not limited just to weapon skills.

Just like critical hits, they always occur on rolls of 3 and 4, and on 5 and 6 for effective skill 15+ and 16+ (respectively). See "Degree of Success or Failure" (*Basic Set: Campaigns*, p. 347) for the general mechanic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. Respectively.  Yes, 3 or 4 counts as a critical success on defence.  But you are rolling against *Defense*, which is 1/2 your Parry plus other PD, so 15 Parry won't, on its own, mean 5 is a critical.  (If your Defense were 15, then 5 would be a critical: but that's nearly impossible with a decent GM).

Edit: Thanks to @Yolgie, whose research means I can explain what I meant.  A defence roll of 5 is a critical miss if and only if your effective skill is 15.  At (3+ 1/2 skill), this means you need a weapon skill of 24, which is way beyond a normal human being; if you are playing Conan the Barbarian at the height of his powers, I imagine the GM will already have some special rules for combat.

Comment: Are you referring to GURPS 3e rules?  If you are referring to 4e, please clarify your answer, as I do not understand.

Comment: Yes, I referred specifically to 3e. I thought 4e was the same in this respect, but can't get at my rules.

Comment: In 4th Edition: "Your Parry active defense with a
given weapon is 3 + half your skill with
that weapon, dropping all fractions" (GURPS Basic Set - Campaigns p.376)

Comment: Since this is calculated against Effective Skill, it's very possible to have a 15+ parry. Enhanced Parry, any Defense Bonus, magic, retreating and/or using a Quarterstaff or fencing weapon...it's relatively easy. A regular mage could use the "Block" spell to get +3 DB and have a Quarterstaff skill of 14 and parry with a Quarterstaff (+2) - easy, realistic 15.